# Windows 7 System File Checker details output

Tags: windows-7

[See this MS article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833)

After I run SFC /scannow

When I run the "edit sfcdetails.txt" command, it says it is an invalid command, tried on 2 Windows 7 PC's, anyone know what the solution is?

I can find the txt file and know how to read it but why does the command not work?

Also when reading the sfcdetails.txt, what does it mean when a file cannot be repaired due to a hash mismatch?

Sample (from a Vista box)

> 2011-06-30 09:32:05, Info                  CSI    0000002f [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"catsrvps.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-COM-ComPlus-Runtime, Version = 6.0.6000.16386, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`edit.com`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS_Editor) command is a 16-bit MS-DOS program, and is not included with 64-bit versions of Windows since you cannot run 16-bit software in 64-bit mode.

You can usually use `notepad` or `more` to view text files.

Comment: Oh so it would work on a 32bit W7 system?

Comment: @Moab: Yes, but why do you require `edit` specifically?

Comment: I added a second question if you could look at it, thanks.

Comment: I don't require it, was just following the directions in the KB article and wondered why it did not work, thinking MS knew what they were talking about, my mistake.

Comment: @Moab I can confirm this answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

The hash is error correction that helps the OS patch up errors that happen in the normal course of using a computer. It also tells the OS if there are errors in the file in the first place.  Sometimes it can fix the errors through some math.  Sometimes though, the damage is so attrocious that it isn't fixable.

If you can system restore, do it. Especially if you had a particularly damaging event recently, like your computer was unexpectedly resetted due to a power failure.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the whole purpose of SFC was to restore a good copy from the file store, how could both be bad?